# c# Enumerable Take method with predicate and result limit

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Is there any extension method in C# for IEnumerable that would return items from collection with predicate until it reaches some given limit?

For example:

```
string[] source = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
var result = source.Take(2, item => item.EndsWith("e"));
// result == { "one", "three" }
```

This example is simple to reflect the idea, but for more complicated logic it could be useful, not to evaluate each item in a collection.

I came up with below solution, but maybe there is something similar in .NET already.

**DO NOT USE BELOW CODE - ONLY FOR REFERENCE**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
    int count,
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (enumerable == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var matchingCount = 0;
        while (matchingCount < count && iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (predicate(iterator.Current))
            {
                matchingCount++;
                yield return iterator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**ELEGANT SOLUTION** - This would do the same:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
    int count,
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return enumerable.Where(predicate).Take(count);
}
```

So by executing following code:

```
string[] source = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }; 
var result = source
    .Where(n => { 
        Console.WriteLine("processing " + n); 
        return n.EndsWith("e"); 
    })
   .Take(2)
   .ToList();
```

Following will be logged in Console:

```
processing one
processing three
```

Hope this will help anyone in the future.

**Remember people : don't reinvent the wheel.**

Comment: You seriously did all of that before taking a look at all methods which IntelliSense quickly enumerates?

Comment: Your example is poorly designed because it does not have a result that would be different from normal "Take(2)".

Comment: Don't break on a null enumerable. **Throw on a null enumerable**.  Null enumerables are not an empty sequence, they are an error.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto actually this is a combination of two methods. I've looked on the documentation but was looking for one.

Comment: @EricLippert my question was if there is a better way of doing this. I need to fix the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine `Take` and `Where`:

```
var result = source.Where(item => item.Contains("e")).Take(2);
```

`Where` while will filter the collection and `Take` will stop the iteration after 2 elements are found. As both `Where` and `Take` are lazy there is no collection being created until iteration, much like your solution, there might be a performance penalty because we have two LINQ operators, but in most cases this should not be an issue.

Comment: yep, I forgot about lazy evaluation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is:

```
var results = source.Where(predicate).Take(limit);
```